# Can sharding work with replication?

Tags: mongodb

Basically we need to have a replication, a minimal setup.

```
Primary
- Slave 1
- Slave 2
```

Is it possible in the future we Shared it? What would be the setup?

Is it going to have shared on Slaves like this?

```
Primary
- Slave 1 (Shared A)
  - Primary
  - Secondary
- Slave 1 (Shared A)
  - Primary
  - Secondary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can definitely work. When you shard, you will need to add nodes equal to your replica count. So it should look like this:

```
Shard0
  - Primary
  - Secondary
  - Secondary
Shard1
  - Primary
  - Secondary
  - Secondary
```

Or put another way, you shard on replica-sets. If your unsharded setup has 3 servers, the 2 shard version should have 6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But yes, sharding and replication work together.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#how-does-sharding-work-with-replication

Anyway, the master-slave replication approach has been discouraged for some time.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/master-slave/

The docs are pretty good, take a look at the replication section.